# Как можно ускорить запрос в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Всем привет! У меня стала проблема со скорость выборки 12+ сек. (MySQL) Есть такой запрос -

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM ( SELECT pitchID 
       FROM LiveDeck 
       WHERE lockID=? 
       GROUP BY pitchID ) AS counter;
```

На таблице есть индекс `(lockID, create_data)`(create_data - datetime) который автоматический используется на данный момент для этого запроса,
и есть индекс `(pitchID, lockID)` для другого запроса. В таблице 20+ мил записей. Пример EXPLAINE этого запроса -

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys        | key                  | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>       | ALL  | NULL                 | NULL                 | NULL    | NULL  | 43878 | NULL                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | LiveDeck         | ref  | lockID_create_time   | lockID_create_time   | 4       | const | 43878 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+----------------------+----------------------+---------+-------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Можно ли ускорить выборку добавив индекс `(lockID, pitchID)` или просто `(lockID)`?
Не будет ли оптимальней distinct вместе group by ? `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pitchID) AS counter FROM LiveDeck WHERE lockID=?;`

Comment: `count(distinct pitchId)` а не эти подзапросы с группировкой

Answer (score -1):

Посмотрите на  https://habr.com/ru/post/41968/ ,   https://www.sql.ru/forum/959500/podskazhite-kak-uskorit-vyborku   ,  https://sqlinfo.ru/forum/viewtopic.php?id=474 . Здесь всё написано.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: думаете за 13 лет с момента написания этих статей ничего не изменилось совсем?

Comment: Спасибо за статьи